# generate fake data with trends

Tags: pandas, numpy

**Context**

I have worked on an analysis for a client whose data is proprietary. I would like to share some of the methods used with others, but replace the data with my own generated data. As an example, I would like to calculate the odds ratio between two features, 'worms' and 'diahrreal_pathogens'.

**Problem**

I know how to generate fake data, but I don't know how to create trends or patterns that would give a result that seems realistic. In my example, I would like the odds ratio p value between 'worms' and 'diahrreal_pathogens' to be less than 0.05 and the OR to be greater than 1, without having a perfect mapping of one to the other. I am not looking for an answer that fine-tunes this, but rather offers a general mechanism for creating fake data with trends.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sample_date': np.random.choice(
        pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=30, freq='D'), 8, replace=False
    ), 
    'age_category': np.random.choice( [1,2,3,4,5] , 8),
    'worms': np.repeat(range(2), 4),
    'diahrreal_pathogens':np.tile(range(2), 4),
    'bhn':np.random.randn(8),
    'latrine':np.random.choice(['improved','basic','none'], 8),
})
>>>df

   age_category       bhn  diahrreal_pathogens   latrine sample_date  worms
0             1 -0.751900                    0      none  2000-01-28      0
1             3  0.619401                    1     basic  2000-01-11      0
2             4  0.085628                    0     basic  2000-01-08      0
3             1  0.564207                    1  improved  2000-01-25      0
4             2  0.701324                    0     basic  2000-01-23      1
5             4  1.237216                    1  improved  2000-01-04      1
6             1  0.000569                    0      none  2000-01-03      1
7             1 -0.324738                    1      none  2000-01-05      1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with binary data, you need to decide exactly what associations you want and hand code the probabilities of each relationship.

So first answer the following questions:

what percent of people with worms should have diahrreal_pathogens?

*60*

of those without worms?

*20*

Now make a function that fills the `diahrreal_pathogens` with those answers as probablilities.

```
def fillPathogens(row):
    if row.worms == 1:
        return np.random.choice([0,1], size=1, p=[.4,.6])
    if row.worms == 0:
        return np.random.choice([0,1], size=1, p=[.8,.2])

df['diahrreal_pathogens'] = df.apply(fillPathogens, axis=1)
```

As your fake dataset size grows, the actual relationships should reflect these probabilities more and more.

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df.diahrreal_pathogens, df.worms)

worms                0  1
diahrreal_pathogens
0                    4  1
1                    0  3
```

Comment: I'm interested to see if people have better solutions before I accept this as the "correct" one.